# Dynamic time warp z score normalisation aint working

Tags: r, time-series, normalization, biostatistics, lags

I have data that looks like this [image]

A bit of background, these are soil moisture graphs of different depths. I wish to investigate how long it takes for water to drip down from one depth to another, and usually there is a bit of lag between when the data jumps upwards (when the soil gets watered) so I'm trying to calculate the lag of the blue graph compared to the red graph. Both graphs share the same x axis and start and end at the same time value.

Below is a z score normalisation attempt, but at the end of the graph, they aren't lined up very well, so this happens:

[image]

Does anyone know how to normalise this better so that the last part of the graph isn't below the other?

As well as this, it does not match well here either. 
A picture of the whole warp
[image]

At the start of the warp:

[image]

Comment: Those pictures are quite aesthetically pleasing, but it is not clear at all what they are showing. You also didn't give us many details on what you are doing, we have no access to your code, so there is not much information for anyone to help you.

Comment: And in addition to what Tim mentioned, include some motivation for why normalization is a good idea here (vs. straight modeling).

Comment: Without further explanations, I can not see why a time warping is used here: the two signals are nicely aligned. Between two successive spikes (or cluster of spikes)  a transfer function model could be used to predict one series from the other if this a concern.